# What is the connection between provability logic & Gödel's first incompleteness theorem?

Tags: logic, goedel, modal-logic

[Provability logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Provability_logic) is a modal logic that interprets the modal operator of K as provability and an additional axiom derived from [Löb's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lob%27s_theorem).

Now the [SEP](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-provability/) shows that it's possible to derive [Gödel's 2nd incompleteness theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godel%27s_incompleteness_theorems#Second_incompleteness_theorem) from this setup. However, what is its connection with [Gödel's 1st incompleteness theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godel%27s_incompleteness_theorems#First_incompleteness_theorem)? It seems unlikely that this is contained within Löb's theorem, as this answered a question by Henkin about sentences that assert their own provability, whereas Gödel investigated sentences that asserted their non-provability.

Comment: minor typo: should be Lob's theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(2 years later) I stumbled across a very nice and clean answer, here goes:

First, let's suppose arithmetic is consistent. If it isn't, Gödel/Rosser is trivially valid since their result is of form "if PA is consistent, then ...".

Assume that you can prove F, or prove ¬F, for each formula F (contrary to Gödel/Rosser's theorem).

If you can prove a certain arbitrary but fixed formula F, then you can also prove Bew([F]), Bew being the standard provability predicate and [] coding (meta)operator. If you can prove ¬F, then you can prove Bew([¬F]). Thus, regardless whether F is provable or ¬F is provable, you can prove (Bew([¬F]) or Bew([F])) for each formula F.

But by Solovay's completeness theorem for provability logic (system GL), formula ([]F or []¬F) should then be a theorem of GL. However, it isn't. Counterexample Kripke model: l[p] <- w -> r[¬p], model is transitive and converse well-founded, but w |=/= ([]p or []¬p).

Comment: Great!  It's as clean and understandable as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

edit: **see my other answer (below or above this one)**.

The second theorem would actually be (ASCII art since we lack LaTeX here):

```
GL |- ~[]_|_ => GL |- _|_,
```

and not what SEP gives a proof of, which is:

```
GL |- []~[]_|_ -> []_|_
```

which is actually a "formalized" version of the second incompleteness theorem (PA talking about itself, again). I don't think the first version given above makes any sense (the "actual" 2. I. T.), since we know `GL |-/- _|_` (that is, that GL is consistent)

So, my guess is that the best you could look for in GL is a formalized version of the first incompleteness theorem.

Perhaps this is a good place to start (the formula below is indeed a theorem, you can check that by trees or direct proof given in Boolos' The Logic of Provability):

```
GL |- [](p <-> ~[]p) -> [](p <-> ~[]_|_)
```

Which can be (roughly) translated as "If (it's provable that) P says that P is unprovable, then P is provable if and only if you can prove consistency".

```
If you assume:
[](p <-> ~[]p)
then 
[](p <-> ~[]_|_),
and if []p, then:
[]~[]_|_, then
[]_|_, while if []~p, then
[]~~[]_|_, that is: [][]_|_
```

So:

```
GL |- ([](p <-> ~[]p) && ([]p or []~p))  -> ([]_|_ or [][]_|_)
```

Perhaps there is even a more direct way to represent the first theorem, I'm not sure. (This would have been a comment if I was allowed to post one. :) ).

Comment: apparently there is :), see my answer (which isn't mine but Peter Smiths).

Comment: If I understood his answer correctly, that's exactly the method I used above (the theorem above states that if P is a fixed point for ~[], in other words if P is a Gödel sentence for PA, than if either P or ~P is provable, either []_|_ or [][]_|_). I'll post a comment there just to be sure!

Comment: @Mikec: Ok, I just found the ascii 'art' a little bit confusing since modal logic is not something I'm comfortable with, though appreciate there is no latex facilities here.

Comment: No problem (I'm still not sure, we'll see). Btw Peter Smith wrote a great intro to these topics, it even includes a bit of GL: http://www.logicmatters.net/igt/further-notes/godel-without-tears

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475254/what-is-the-connection-between-provability-logic-godels-first-incompleteness) answer by Peter Smith:

> As you say, you can get the second incompleteness theorem from the Hilbert-Bernays-Löb derivability conditions on the provability predicate (which are what are reflected in the modal "provability logic") together with the diagonalization lemma which tells us that there is a fixed point for 'not provable'. But you need the diagonalization lemma for the standard proof of the second theorem using the derivability conditions (no?).
>
> And that diagonalization lemma, of course, will give you the first theorem almost immediately.

So, the answer is yes.